# Safari WebDriver can't submit in a text box

Tags: selenium, safari, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test a simple webapp with Selenium. The use case is:

- start [here](http://mithril-test.cos.io/basic/)
- click the 'todo' link in the first list
- type something into the text box
- click the button

Then, the last item in the list should have the value that was typed in, and the text box should be empty.

In Safari (v7.0.5 (9537.77.4)) on OS X (10.9.4), this works correctly when performed manually.  This also works when performed using Selenium to drive Chrome. However, when done with Selenium through the Safari WebDriver, the item added is simply an empty string.

The odd part is that the `value` attribute of the `input` element has the correct value after the WebDriver types the text; the value just doesn't get added to the list, like it does when the actions are performed manually.

Below is code to reproduce the behavior. Does anyone have any insight?

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://mithril-test.cos.io/basic/'

d = webdriver.Safari()

    try:
    # navigate to 'http://mithril-test.cos.io/basic/'
    d.get(url)

    # click 'todo' link
    d.find_element_by_link_text('todo').click()

    # type in 'whatevs' in the input field
    input_text = 'test'
    d.find_element_by_tag_name('input').send_keys(input_text)

    # the 'value' attribute of the input field is the thing we just typed
    assert d.find_element_by_tag_name('input').get_attribute('value') == input_text

    # click the submit button
    d.find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()

    todo_text = d.find_elements_by_tag_name('ul')[1].text
    # passes: the list is 'one' 'two': incorrect behavior
    assert todo_text == 'one\ntwo'
    # fails: the list should be 'one' 'two' plus the thing we typed in: correct behavior
    assert todo_text == 'one\ntwo\n' + input_text

except:
    raise

finally:
    d.close()
```

Comment: I couldn't able to see the `value` part.

Comment: @Ant's sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Is there something I can clarify or fix in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the Safari WebDriver's implementation, as described [in this issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4061). In particular, typing behavior is implemented in JavaScript, which causes a number of limitations as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5403).

My workaround for the moment is to fire the change event in the test itself.